# Bash - create menu, read variables from keyboard

Tags: bash, menu, stdin

I'm trying to build a menu in Bash:

echo Option1
echo Option2
echo Option3
echo Option4
...
Option3 = ls -l /home/test/|wc -l

Now, if the users selects option 3 for instance, I would like bash to call a Linux command specific to Option 3.

I've been able to read what users enters from the keyboard, however I'm not able to link the Option 3 for instance with the number 3 that user enters on the keyboard:

$ Which option would you like: 3
You have selected Option3. Would you like to continue?Y

You have 20 files in the home directory.

Something like that.

Comment: Please format your question; it's hard to understand what you've written. It's also a good idea to show us the code you've already tried, and to try searching the web before you post, especially for questions that others are very likely to have asked.

See http://askubuntu.com/questions/1705/how-can-i-create-a-select-menu-in-a-shell-script for an example. (Or search the web for "bash menu".)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using `read` to get the user input, it shows up (by default) in the `REPLY` variable, which you can then test with something like:

```
read
if [[ "${REPLY}" = "3" ]] ; then
    echo You entered 3
fi
```

If you want your input in a different variable, you can just supply that with the commend:

```
read userinput
if [[ "${userinput}" = "3" ]] ; then
: : (and so on)
```

If there are lots of possibilities, you're probably better off using `case` instead of a lot of `if/else` lines, an example which is shown below:

```
case "${userinput}" in
    0)
        echo You entered zero.
        ;;
    [1-9]*)
        echo You entered something starting with one through nine.
        ;;
    *)
        echo What?
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

## select

It sounds like what you want is bash's `select` command which shows you a numbered list of items and then gets a response.

### Example

```sh
select name in "option 1" "option 2" "option 3"
do
    echo "You picked $name"
    break
done
```

```
./select.sh 
1) option 1
2) option 2
3) option 3
#? 3
You picked option 3
```

### Here is what the Bash manpage has to say about select:

> **select** *name* [ **in** *word* ] ; **do** *list* ; **done**
>
> The list of words following **in** is expanded, generating a list
>   of items.  The set of expanded words is printed on the standard
>   error, each preceded by a number.  If the **in** *word* is
>   omitted, the positional parameters are printed.  The **PS3**
>   prompt is then displayed and a line read from the standard input.
>   If the line consists of a number corresponding to one of the
>   displayed words, then the value of *name* is set to that word.  If
>   the line is empty, the words and prompt are displayed again.  If
>   EOF is read, the command completes.  Any other value read causes
>   *name* to be set to null.  The line read is saved in the variable
>   **REPLY**.  The *list* is executed after each selection until a **break**
>   command is executed.  The exit status of **select** is the exit
>   status of the last command executed in *list*, or zero if no
>   commands were executed.

### A better example of `select`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

options+=("butter" "scotch" "tape" "monkey" "nut")
options+=("some atrociously long option")

select name in "${options[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$name" ]]; then
        echo "You selected $name"
    else
        echo "You typed in: $REPLY"
        name=$REPLY
    fi

    case "$name" in
        butter) echo "I say butterscotch"
                ;;
        scotch) echo "I say scotchtape"
                ;;
        tape) echo "I say tapemonkey"
                ;;
        monkey) echo "I say monkeynut"
                ;;
        nut) echo "I say nutbutter"
                ;;
        "some atrocious"*)
            echo "You win!"
            break
            ;;
        *)
            echo "I'm stumped. Goodbye."
            break
            ;;
    esac        
done
```

```
$ ./select.sh 
1) butter                        4) monkey
2) scotch                        5) nut
3) tape                          6) some atrociously long option
#? 3

You selected tape
I say tapemonkey
#? 4

You selected monkey
I say monkeynut
#? nut

You typed in: nut
I say nutbutter
#? butternut

You typed in: butternut
I'm stumped. Goodbye.
$
```